# Command Line (or batch file) rename all files in a folder (Windows)

Tags: windows, batch-file, command, cmd, batch-rename

I need to rename all of the files in a folder with the following filename format;

itemID-straight-bottle.png

TO

itemID-bottle.png

How can i accomplish this with a cmd script or in the command line?

example;

REDHI20806-straight-bottle.png TO REDHI20806-bottle.png

I should have said, this is in Windows and i want to use either command line or a batch file to run this renaming on all files in a folder on a specific drive

Comment: Are you asking about Unix or Windows? In Unix may try following: `for i in *.png; do mv "$i" "$(echo $i | sed 's|\(.\+\)-straight\(-bottle.png\)$|\1\2|')"; done`

Comment: Windows sorry, i want to do this from a command prompt or batch file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### short answer

On **Windows**, you can use PowerShell, that is installed by default on Windows 7, and can be downloaded and installed on previous versions. With PowerShell you can do the rename as:

```sh
ls | foreach-object -process {ren $_ (%{$_ -replace "-straight",""})}
```

On **Unix/Linux**, nothing specific needs to be installed, and you can do the rename as:

```sh
ls | awk '{print("mv "$1" "$1)}' | cut -f -3,5- -d '-' | sh
```

### examples

### Windows Example

#### *Given*

```sh
PS C:\rename-me> ls

    Directory: C:\rename-me

Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---         10/9/2011   1:35 PM          0 REDHI20806-straight-bottle.png
-a---         10/9/2011   1:35 PM          0 REDHI20807-straight-bottle.png
-a---         10/9/2011   1:35 PM          0 REDHI20808-straight-bottle.png
-a---         10/9/2011   1:35 PM          0 REDHI20809-straight-bottle.png
-a---         10/9/2011   1:35 PM          0 REDHI20810-straight-bottle.png
```

#### *Doing It*

```sh
PS C:\rename-me> ls | foreach-object -process {ren $_ (%{$_ -replace "-straight",""})}
```

#### *Result*

```sh
PS C:\rename-me> ls

    Directory: C:\rename-me

Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---         10/9/2011   1:35 PM          0 REDHI20806-bottle.png
-a---         10/9/2011   1:35 PM          0 REDHI20807-bottle.png
-a---         10/9/2011   1:35 PM          0 REDHI20808-bottle.png
-a---         10/9/2011   1:35 PM          0 REDHI20809-bottle.png
-a---         10/9/2011   1:35 PM          0 REDHI20810-bottle.png
```

### Unix/Linux Example

#### *Given*

```sh
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  0 Oct  7 00:54 REDHI20806-straight-bottle.png
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  0 Oct  7 00:54 REDHI20807-straight-bottle.png
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  0 Oct  7 00:54 REDHI20808-straight-bottle.png
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  0 Oct  7 00:54 REDHI20809-straight-bottle.png
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  0 Oct  7 00:54 REDHI20810-straight-bottle.png
```

#### *Doing It*

```sh
$ ls | awk '{print("mv "$1" "$1)}' | cut -f -3,5- -d '-' | sh
```

#### *Result*

```sh
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  0 Oct  7 00:54 REDHI20806-bottle.png
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  0 Oct  7 00:54 REDHI20807-bottle.png
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  0 Oct  7 00:54 REDHI20808-bottle.png
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  0 Oct  7 00:54 REDHI20809-bottle.png
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  0 Oct  7 00:54 REDHI20810-bottle.png
```

Comment: Given that i am not well versed in command line coding, i have no idea what to do with what you have given me sorry!

Comment: I need to do this for all files in a certain directory on a specific drive, is this something i can run in a cmd file?

Comment: @MartinaL, the example I gave you is for *nix systems. But on Windows you can install [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) or [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) to be able to Unix like commands.

Comment: I have PowerShell installed but am not really sure how to use it. I tired your commands but all i get is an error

Comment: I don't know any unix so if anyone knows how to do this with a windows batch file or in the command line that would be really helpfel

Comment: added an example in PowerShell to the answer

Answer (score 2):

if only the last part of the filename (`straight-bottle.png`) needs to change (to `bottle.png`) you can simply do this:

```
REN ??????????-straight-bottle.png ??????????-bottle.png
```

(I did not test this though)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going with a modified version of [wimh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7703162/1006269) but instead of "??????????", I used "*" which I think better handles names of different lengths.

```
ren *-straight-bottle.png *-bottle.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would use a tool designed specifically for bulk renaming, e.g. [renamer](https://github.com/75lb/renamer).

This command strips out the `-straight` text from all files in the current directory:

```
$ renamer --find=-straight --dry-run *

Dry run

✔︎ REDHI20806-straight-bottle.png → REDHI20806-bottle.png
✔︎ GRNHI30030-straight-bottle.png → GRNHI30030-bottle.png

Rename complete: 2 of 2 files renamed.
```