# How to bulk-rename files

Tags: batch-file

How can I bulk-rename files from a batch file?

Given:

```
_(jkhjkhjkhjkhjkhk)_file1.txt
_(jkhjk2342343hjkhjkhk)_file2.txt
_(jkhjk2342343khjkhk)_file3.txt
```

I want to create a batch file rename those to:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Command Line (or batch file) rename all files in a folder (Windows)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7683048/command-line-or-batch-file-rename-all-files-in-a-folder-windows)

Comment: [renamer](https://github.com/75lb/renamer) is perfect for jobs like this - it supports regex renaming

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "targetdir=U:\destdir"
COPY NUL %targetdir%\"_(jkhjkhjkhjkhjkhk)_file1.txt" >nul
COPY NUL %targetdir%\"_(jkhjk2342343hjkhjkhk)_file2.txt" >nul
COPY NUL %targetdir%\"_(jkhjk2342343khjkhk)_file3.txt" >nul
FOR %%a IN ("%targetdir%\_*_*.txt") DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=2delims=_" %%b IN ("%%~na") DO (
  ECHO REN "%%~fa" "%%b.txt"
 )
)
GOTO :EOF
```

This should get you running.

the `copy` commands are simply to create the files in the test directory `u:\destdir`

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.